# How to build a json of this form

Tags: java, json

How can I generate JSON with this format using JAVA:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "760e4770-0006-4572-a4e3-d830f3425e5c",
        }
    ]
}
```

> Note: After userId, I need to add ','.

I used a `HashMap` and `ArrayList` while generating the above JSON. But, I am unable to add the required comma(,) after the userId. How I can I get it to add the comma. Can any one help me?

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: Why do you need to add a `,` when this would make it invalid JSON?

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: Just google JSON in Java. There are many libraries that can help you make valid JSON object, like this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Answer (score 4):

It is only valid to use a comma when there are additional properties to follow.

Example:

```
{
   "users": [
        {     
            "userId":"760e4770-0006-4572-a4e3-d830f3425e5c",
            "another":"here",
            "and":"finally" 
        }
    ] 
}
```

So in regards to your sample, the trailing comma after the `userId` property is not required.

http://jsonlint.com/ is a great online tool for checking your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another user object, the json should be in the below format.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "1"
        }, 
        {
            "userId": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want other attributes of user object, then each key value pair is seperated by ",".

```
{   "users":
        [
             {     
                      "userId":"760e4770-0006-4572-a4e3-d830f3425e5c", 
                      "userName": "xxx"
              }
         ] 
}
```

Refer this http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
After forming a valid Json, I build the above using the following lines,  



hmap.put("userName",username);                                              
hmap.put("email", email);
List<Map<String, Object>> listObj=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
listObj.add(hmap);
hmap1.put("newUsers",listObj);
```